# Relativistic flashlight and mirror

Tags: special-relativity

Say Alice is on on one end of a train moving at c/2 and there is a mirror at the other end.  If she turns on a flashlight aimed at the mirror, from her perspective it takes the same time for the light to reach the mirror as it does for the reflected light to then come back to her.  But from Bob's perspective, it takes longer for the light to reach the mirror as it is moving away as the light approaches.  After it reflects off the mirror, Alice is moving toward the light, shortening the return trip.

Is it just a flawed assumption that two events that appear to be the same time apart in one inertial reference frame will appear to be the same time apart in another (even if the observed time is different)?

How does relativity account for the 'paradox' I seem to have run into when thinking relativisticly?

Comment: *"How does relativity account for the 'paradox' I seem to have run into when thinking relativisticly?"*  According to Bob, Alice's clocks are not synchronized.  According to Alice, Bob's clocks are not synchronized.

Comment: This [one](http://web.hep.uiuc.edu/home/g-gollin/relativity/p112_relativity_8.html) should help you.

Comment: "Is it just a flawed assumption that two events that appear to be the same time apart in one inertial reference frame will appear to be the same time apart in another (even if the observed time is different)?"  Yes, this is a false assumption.

Comment: What is the downvote on the question for?  What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to answer my own question (with some thought spurred by Alfred Centauri), the issue is that Alice and the mirror, don't agree on when Alice turned on her flashlight.  By replacing the mirror with Eve who can start a timer with Alice and turn on her own flashlight when she sees the light from Alice things start to make a little more (or less, because relativity is like that) sense.

First, Alice and Eve need to agree when to start their timers.  Let's say there is a light half way between them on the train, and when each sees the light from it, they should start their timers.  When Alice sees the light, she turns on her flashlight and starts her timer at the same time.  When Eve sees the light from Alice's flashlight, Eve stops her stopwatch.

From the train's perspective, the light reaches each of them at the same time.  The light from Alice's flashlight takes x amount of time to reach Eve, and then the light from Eve's flashlight takes the same x amount of time to reach Alice.

To make the math a little cleaner, let's say the train is moving c/3 relative to Bob.

```
   Bob

            X
-1  A _ _ _ s _ _ _ E

     <           >
 0   0A _ _ _ s _ _ _ E

           >           >
 1     1A _ _ _ s _ _ _ E0

                 >
 2      2A _ _ _ s _ _ _ E1

                       >
 3        3A _ _ _ s _ _ _ E2

                             >
 4          4A _ _ _ s _ _ _ E3

                       <
 5            5A _ _ _ s _ _ _ E3

                 < 
 6              6A _ _ _ s _ _ _ E
```

-1 Signal sent

0 Signal reaches Alice, but not yet Eve. Alice's timer has started.

1 Signal has now reached Eve so she starts her timer, but Alice has already turned on her flashlight.

2-3 Light from Alice's flashlight is in transit.

4 Alice's light reaches Eve so she stops her timer at 3 and turns on her flashlight. Bob notes the time at 4.

5 Light from Eve's flashlight is in transit.

6 Light from Eve's flashlight reaches Alice and she stops her timer at 6, exactly twice the reading from Eve's stopwatch, just as expected from the train's perspective. However, Bob reads the time as 6-4, 2. Or half the time it took the light to reach Eve.

I was careful not to use a time unit such as seconds because, due to time dilation, Bob doesn't agree with Alice and Eve on how long a second is, or how long the train is for that matter.  The important thing is Alice and Eve observed it taking the same length of time for the light to leave Alice and reach Eve as it did for the light to leave Eve and reach Alice, but Bob did not observe them being the same.  However, Bob could see why Alice and Eve would think it took the same time.

The flaw in the assumption was that the distance in space between Alice and the mirror/
Eve has to be taken into account.  Just because two time spans are the same in one inertial reference frame, doesn't mean they will be the same in another, not when the events are separated in space.